# FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener updating state after registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am observing the Firebase Authentication State from my MainActivity to handle login and sign our events. This works fine for the most part, however when I select an image from the gallery using registerForActivityResult in my Fragment, the Authentication State logs another "authenticated" change and runs the code within the observer.

Why would the Authentication State being observed again if nothing has changed?

MainActivity.kt:

```
    private fun observeAuthenticationState() {

    viewModel.authenticationState.observe(this, Observer { authenticationState ->
        when (authenticationState) {
            MainViewModel.AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED -> {
                //If the user is logged in,
                Timber.i("User is authenticated")
                NavigateOnLogin()
            }
            else -> {
                // If there is no logged-in user,
                Timber.i("User is NOT authenticated")
                findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav).visibility = View.GONE
                findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigate(R.id.loginFragment)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

MainViewModel.kt:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel()  {

    enum class AuthenticationState {
        AUTHENTICATED, UNAUTHENTICATED, INVALID_AUTHENTICATION
    }

    val authenticationState = FirebaseUserLiveData().map { user ->
        if (user != null) {
            Timber.i("Authenticated!!!!!")
            AuthenticationState.AUTHENTICATED
        } else {
            AuthenticationState.UNAUTHENTICATED
            Timber.i("Unauthenticated!!!!!")
        }
    }
}
```

FirebaseUserLiveData.kt

```
class FirebaseUserLiveData : LiveData<FirebaseUser?>() {
    private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    private val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->

        value = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}
```

Fragment.kt

```
        val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
                // Handle the returned Uri
                
   }
    
    override fun onCreateView(): View? {
    
            binding.imageViewProfileImage.setOnClickListener{
                getContent.launch("image/*")
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time implementing Firebase sign-in with Google, I recommend you check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) out.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo. Using One Tap sign in now.